# excel vba make a cell flash/blink

Tags: excel, colors, cell

I am trying to get a cell to flash for a finite time.  The code I have so far (with help from another member) is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim waitTime As Date, stopTime As Date

Function startFlash(x As String)
    Beep
    stopTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 2, 0)
    'Debug.Print stopTime
    Call sflash
    MsgBox "done"
End Function

Sub sflash()

    Sheet1.Range("c8").Font.ColorIndex = 3

    Do While waitTime <= stopTime

        With Sheet1.Range("c8").Font
            If .ColorIndex = 3 Then
              .ColorIndex = 5
             Else
              .ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End With

        waitTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        'Debug.Print Now; waitTime; stopTime

        Do While Now < waitTime: DoEvents: Loop
    Loop

End Sub
```

This procedure is called from a cell in a worksheet with the following code:

```
=if(C8>25,"yup",startFlash(C8))
```

And C8 has a number placed into it.

When it runs it successfully and properly goes through the loops and the colorIndex value does change with every iteration.  However, cell C8 does not change color until I hit ok after the message "done" pops up.

I have tried it with and without

```
application.screenupdating = false/true
```

before and after 'with'/'end with'.

I cannot find a solution to make the cell change color when the ColorIndex changes i.e. make the cell flash/blink.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any spreadsheet that requires blinking/flashing cells has serious design problems.

Comment: The user wants to quickly identify any cells on a large spreadsheet that have changed with a resultant value > 25. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Use conditional formatting to compare cells and highlight differences.

Comment: I started to look at that but was wondering how to get it into a loop.  Maybe it will be ok to leave a red 'down arrow' in that cell vs having it flash.   Just because its driving me crazy, can you suggest reasons why, in my code, the font colors aren't changing?  Thx